# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. When trying to create a button.

Tags: actionscript-3, button, null, movie, clip

Heyy, Im having some problems with my buttons. What I have is 4 buttons on the page. They will run an animation while not being pressed, and that animation will change when it is being pressed.

I keep getting the error TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at MultimediaAssignment_fla::MainTimeline/frame51()[MultimediaAssignment_fla.MainTimeline::frame51:3]

And I have searched high and low but I cant seem to find anyone who is having the same problem as me.

```
stop();

btn_volcano.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, volcano);
btn_Storm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stormbtn);
btn_Tsunami.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tsunamibtn);
btn_Earthquake.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, earthquakebtn);


function volcano(e:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(52);
}

function tsunamibtn(e:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(54);
}

function stormbtn(e:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(53);
}

function earthquakebtn(e:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(55);
}
```

My buttons do have correct instance names and for some reason it worked when I turned the "up" movie clip into a button and called it e.g. btn_volcano. Except if I do that the animation doesn't run anymore.

If I remove the instance name from in front of the event listener I don't get the error but it will only ever run the last code.

Please help!

Comment: It's btn_volcano, or btn_Volcano? I noticed that all the other movie clips have the second word capitalized.

Comment: Cristina is right - there is some problem with the linkage. Double check and rename if needed. Commonly some space character can be found at the end.. There is no other reason :)

Comment: The only reason I changed the cap to a small letter was to see if I had written something wrong or if it just needed to see a different word. Which didn't work. I will check for the space at the end of the word though.

Answer (score 0):

error TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at MultimediaAssignment_fla::MainTimeline/frame51()

This line suggests you have some code in frame 51. I presume in Flash IDE in main timeline.
Click on this frame on timeline and open actions window. Problem may be there.